# How to combine Swashbuckle filters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swashbuckle

What I need is using some condition to hide or show some properties of a model in **Model|Example Value** of response in Swagger UI.

How could this be realized? My condition is based on attributes on api actions and on properties of a DTO. So, f.e., if an action provides an attribute then we should only see the tagged properties in Swagger UI.

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner to actually create separate models for the different use cases? You could have a base class with the shared properties and derived classes with the properties only for the specific actions.

Comment: @ChristophHerold this is the strategy that we would not wish because of hardly maintenance. Actualy by that trick we want to do vice-versa

Comment: You really think it is harder to maintain proper models than maintaining proper attributes? I don't see the difference, other than that having proper models will prevent you from using something in your service code, that should not be available via your API. Just because a property is not documented in Swagger, it will not prevent someone from actually specifying that property, and it being deserialized into your models.

Comment: @ChristophHerold it will not be serialized because we have custom serializer, so there much more reasons than I could describe here

Comment: Shows us some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. You only need to implement `IOperationFilter` and register it. This stuff allows you to show customized different examples for the same model.

---

**DTO**

```
public class MyDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ShortModelMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**Method in API controller**

```
[HttpGet]
[ReturnShortModel]
public MyDTO GetSmthg()
{
    return MyDTO.GetExample();
}
```

**Swagger's custom operation filter**

```
public class SwaggerExcludeFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        if (!apiDescription.GetControllerAndActionAttributes<ReturnShortModelAttribute>().Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        var responseType = apiDescription.ResponseDescription.DeclaredType;
        var description = $"OK (uses a short model of {responseType})";
        var props = responseType
                    .GetProperties()
                    .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ShortModelMemberAttribute)).Any())
                    .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p.PropertyType.Name);
        }

        operation.responses.Clear();
        operation.responses.Add("200", new Response
        {
            description = description,
            schema = new Schema
            {
                example = props,
            },
        });
    }
}
```

**And finally**

```
c.OperationFilter<SwaggerExcludeFilter>();
```